# How to resolve Spring Data Neo4j Rest Dependency on class that does not exist

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to use the Spring-Data Neo4j Rest project as part of an unmanaged Neo4j Extension as I wish to inject a list of implementations into a

I've been following the example here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/reference_neo4j-server.html#d0e4306

Which uses the class `SpringPluginInitializer`

However this class has a dependency on the class `org.neo4j.helper.Pair` which does not exist in the Neo4j Kernel Project I am using (there is a class `org.neo4j.helpers.collection.Pair` but not `org.neo4j.helper.Pair`).

I'm using Neo4j version 3.0.5 and Spring Data Neo4j 3.4.6.RELEASE which I believe are the latest versions of both.

Is there anyway to get around this issue? Or is there another approach I could take to use the Spring injection functionality that doesn't rely on the `SpringPluginInitializer` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.x is not the current major version of Spring Data Neo4, 4.x is (currently, [4.1.5](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/), with 4.2.0 under way).

In particular, SDN 3.x predates Neo4j 3.x, in which some classes (including `Pair`) were reorganized in different packages, i.e. they can be incompatible.

Comment: The latest version doesn't include the SpringPluginInitialiser that the tutorial uses, but then I found out I didn't need it anyway as I could just use normal Spring injection which work fine.
Thank you for the help though